# Why string compare returns -1 even though both strings are same?

Tags: string, tcl

I am getting -1 instead of 0 in string comparison
I have used following code

```
set s1 "sekhar" 
set s2 "sekhar"
puts [string compare s1 s2]
```

Comment: post some code that demonstrates the problem. Chances are you are not comparing what you think you are comparing.

Comment: It should be `puts [string compare $s1 $s2]`

Comment: @Dinesh, please consider turning your comment into a proper answer providing a link to the Tcl tutorial.

Comment: hi dinesh thanks for reply ,but my query was  set1 "sekhar1 sekhar2 sekhar3...........sekharn     set2 "sekhar1 sekhar3............sekharn"

Comment: how can i say that sekhar2 is missing s2

Comment: This is a completely another story. Please post another question, and roll back your last edit. I mean, you actually have two separate problems (properly using variables and finding the difference between two sets of values) so let's manage them with two separate questions.

Comment: @kostix I think that, if only the dollar signs were missing, then the Q should be closed as being off topic for typing error, or possibly a dup if there's a similar one somewhere deep in SO.

Comment: I've rolled back that edit. If you have a different question, _ask a different question!_ As a separate question in the Stack Overflow interface. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
string compare s1 s2
```

You are comparing the *string literals* `s1` and `s2`. Since `s1` is lesser according to the rules (which are basically the same as for the C `strcmp()` function with enhancements) you get `-1` as result.

To compare the strings with those names, you *need* to read the variables before feeding them into `string compare`. You do this by prefixing the names with `$` (which in Tcl means “read this variable right now”):

```
string compare $s1 $s2
```

Internally, Tcl passes values around by reference and reduces variable accesses to indexes into a local variable table where it can (i.e., in procedures). This operation is actually pretty fast in practice.